# Is there a way to remove duplicate tags?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

TFS 2015 Update 1
Over the years we've been using TFS we've been pretty good using the Tag feature to help us better categorize and find work items.  However, a few duplicate tags have been entered.  For example:
       "ourSite.com" and "ourSitecom"

These kinds of "duplicates" cause our queries to not find, for example, every "ourSite.com" tagged work item.

Is there a way in TFS 2015, to remove duplicate tags from TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it's not a *duplicate*, it's a misspelling or different spelling. The only solution is manually retagging appropriately.

Comment: ... as I feared.  Understood that its not a duplicate.  It just "appears to be"  from our stakeholder's perspective.  Re-tagging, how bad could it be? -- thanks.